# how to get Summation of Calculated value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
        select sum(Weight) as 'PP04' from dbo.tbl_insertxmldetails where 
        Section in (select Material from [Mst_tbl_ExtMaterialGroupList] 
        where [Ext# Matl Group] = 'PP04') and
        OrderName like @jobno+'%'
```

--PP12

```
         select sum(Weight) as 'PP12' from dbo.tbl_insertxmldetails where 
         Section in (select Material from [Mst_tbl_ExtMaterialGroupList] 
         where [Ext# Matl Group] = 'PP12') and
         OrderName like @jobno+'%'
```

i want to write Stored procedure for Caluclating the some of PP04 and PP12 in same Stored Procedure .How can I write query in single statement .

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure calcProc as
   declare @returnValue int

   select @returnValue = sum(Weight) as 'PP04' ...
   select @returnValue = @returnValue  + sum(Weight) as 'PP12' ...

   select @returnValue 
go
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how you want to return the total sum or whether you still want to return the partial sums along with the total.

If you want only the total value, use the following query instead of the other two:

```
SELECT
  Total = SUM(Weight)
FROM dbo.tbl_insertxmldetails
WHERE x.OrderName LIKE @jobno + '%'
  AND Section IN (
    SELECT Material
    FROM [Mst_tbl_ExtMaterialGroupList] 
    WHERE [Ext# Matl Group] IN ('PP04', 'PP12')
  )
;
```

If you want all three values, you should specify whether you want them as separate columns of a single row:

```
PP04   PP12   Total
-----  -----  -----
…      …      …
```

or in a single column but in separate rows:

```
Ext# Matl Group  Weight
---------------  ------
PP04             …
PP12             …
Total            …
```

If the former (single row, separate columns), here's one way to accomplish that:

```
SELECT
  PP04  = SUM(CASE m.[Ext# Matl Group] WHEN 'PP04' THEN x.Weight END),
  PP12  = SUM(CASE m.[Ext# Matl Group] WHEN 'PP12' THEN x.Weight END),
  Total = SUM(x.Weight)
FROM dbo.tbl_insertxmldetails AS x
  INNER JOIN Mst_tbl_ExtMaterialGroupList AS m ON x.Section = m.Material
WHERE m.[Ext# Matl Group] IN ('PP04', 'PP12')
  AND x.OrderName LIKE @jobno + '%'
;
```

And if you want the results in separate rows, then you could try grouping with rollup:

```
SELECT
  [Ext# Matl Group] = COALESCE(m.[Ext# Matl Group], 'Total'),
  Weight            = SUM(x.Weight)
FROM dbo.tbl_insertxmldetails AS x
  INNER JOIN Mst_tbl_ExtMaterialGroupList AS m ON x.Section = m.Material
WHERE m.[Ext# Matl Group] IN ('PP04', 'PP12')
  AND x.OrderName LIKE @jobno + '%'
GROUP BY
  ROLLUP(m.[Ext# Matl Group])
;
```

Note: if your database is in SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode, `GROUP BY ROLLUP()` won't work. In that case use the older syntax:

```
…
GROUP BY
  m.[Ext# Matl Group]
WITH ROLLUP
```